# How to write a unit test for model have appends property

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I have the model Products, which has the protected property `$appends = ['avg_rating']`. This avg rating is being set by an `getAvgRatingAttribute()` function. I want to write a unit test for append property in the model Products, so any ideas?

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $appends = [
        'avg_rating',
    ];
    
    public function getAvgRatingAttribute()
    {
        return $this->comments()->avg('rating');
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't understand why you would want to test this because it feels like you are trying to test framework functionality, but, you should be able to access the appended attribute like any other attribute.. Do you want to test if the model has the appended property or if it's returning the correct average?

Comment: I want to test the model has the appended property and it's returning the correct avg. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to test the model has the appended property and it's returning
> the correct avg. Do you have any idea?

```
//use Tests\TestCase;
public function test_your_test_name(){
 $post = Post::create([]);
 $post->comments()->saveMany([
   new Comment(['rating' => 2]),
   new Comment(['rating' => 4]),
   new Comment(['rating' => 1]),
  ]);

 $this->assertTrue(isset($post->avg_rating)); //to test if attribute is set
 $this->assertEquals(  (2+4+1)/3, $post->avg_rating ); //test if avg rating is correct
}
```

I maybe missing the point, but, I should say that these tests seem unnecessary. This is the same as testing if `getAvgRatingAttribute` sets the attribute, and if `avg` function returns the correct average, which, the framework has already tested.